# Series and sequences exercise

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that for every convergent serie $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ such that $a_n\ge 0$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$. Exist a sequence ({$b_n$}) such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=0$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_nb_n$ converge.

I have tried that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ converge so we know that exist $N$ such that for all $m,n$ with $m>n>N$ we have |$\sum^{m}_n a_n$|<ϵ. But I can not figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure you stated this correctly? As stated you could just let $b_n=0$. A more interesting question is to do the same with a sequence such that $b_n\to\infty$.

Comment: I double check it

Comment: So could I just take $b_n=0$ and I would have proved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any sequence $(b_n)$ which has positive terms and tends to $0$, e.g. $b_n=\frac1n$. If $n$ is large enough,$0\le b_n<1$ so
$$0\le a_nb_n<a_n,$$
and $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_nb_n$ converges by the *comparison theorem*.

Comment: Could you provide me the comparison theorem?

Comment: If series have positive terms, $\sum_n a_n$ converges and $b_n\le a_n$ for all $n$ large enough, then $\sum_n b_n$ converges too.